# How to automatically enter user password when prompted by terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, scp

If I am working in a terminal that is currently `SSH` logged in to a remote server `user@node`, and I want to transfer a file **from** local **to** that same server, I will run:

```
scp you@your_local_machine:/home/you/"FileName.csv" user@node:"~/folder"
```

It'll then ask for my local machine's login password. This is fine, but is there a way that I can modify the above `scp` call to automatically enter my password to the terminal instead of needing to type it in manually?

Comment: You can setup ssh keys so that you can use passwordless logins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSH (Secure Shell) can be set up [with public/private key pairs](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html) so that you don't have to type the password each time.
On the local machine,type

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

[image]

To get the key on the server, you have two choices:

- Use `ssh-copy-id` (standard with most Linuxes), e.g. `ssh-copy-id user@server`
- Paste the content of the local `~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` file into the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote host.